# postman status : 405 and method not allowed

Tags: spring-boot, postman

iam trying to create a user springboot project and while im going to saveUser in postman it showing method not allowed and not allowed to save in mysqworkbench
`[User Controller.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhL57.png)`

i attached user controller can anyone check

Comment: i am sure you are doing `GET` request instead of `POST` in postman